# MarkLogic data movement in the Node.js API - queryAll()

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-11

The bug has been resolved as of version 3.3.1.

---

It's a bug, and a patch release is forthcoming. This workaround —courtesy of Phil Barber, a contributor to the repository — worked for me in the meantime. I appreciate the prompt responses, everyone!

> `In the meantime, the work-around is to not have the "database" property in the connection settings and to use a REST port with the correct database assigned.`

Here's [the issue link](https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/issues/837) for anyone who wants to track any updates.

---

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could share their expertise regarding an issue I'm encountering with `queryAll()` function in the MarkLogic data movement Node.js API.

I attempted a simple `queryAll()` example, which resulted in the following error:

> MarkLogicError: read forestInfo: cannot process response with 405 status with path.

Is this function currently operational? Do I need to make any additional configuration or permission changes, or install any extra plugins?

[The MarkLogic documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/datamovement) references the queryAll() function, and there's [an example query on GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/3.3.0/examples/queryAll-documents.js). When it comes to reading bulk data, is custom data service a more preferred approach?

Here is some additional context:

- MarkLogic's documentation on 'data movement in the Node.js API': https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/datamovement
- queryAll() example on GitHub: https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/master/examples/queryAll-documents.js
- Below is the simple code example that I got the 405 status error:

```
const marklogic = require("marklogic");
const connection = require("./settings").connection;
const db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(connection);
const qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;
const ctsQb = marklogic.ctsQueryBuilder;

const query = qb.where(ctsQb.cts.directoryQuery(["/object/"]));

try {
  db.documents.queryAll(query, {
    onCompletion: (summary) => {
      console.log(summary.urisReadSoFar+' uris were retrieved successfully.');
      console.log(summary.urisFailedToBeRead+' uris failed to be retrieved.');
      console.log('Time taken was '+summary.timeElapsed+' milliseconds.');
    },
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.error("QueryAll Error: ", err);
}
```

- I confirmed the simple cts query works in this simpler query example:

```
const query = qb.where(ctsQb.cts.directoryQuery(["/object/"]));
db.documents.query(query).result(
  (documents) => {
    documents.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc);
    });
    console.log(`${documents.length} uris were retrieved successfully.`);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  }
);
```

- Additionally, the REST API access log shows the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1 - admin [28/Jan/2024:17:57:48 -0500] "POST /v1/internal/forestinfo&database=my-db-dev HTTP/1.1" 405 0 - -
```

- It's a local MarkLogic 11 instance (not datahub), and the request was run with MarkLogic admin user privileges.

I've only found the limited stuff I mentioned above when looking up this Node.js function. Any help you can give would be great.

Comment: Are you connecting to a REST API app server - i.e. one with a URL rewriter of "/MarkLogic/rest-api/rewriter.xml"?

Comment: Yes, I am. I will test using a fresh, basic REST API setup to determine if the issue is related to my specific configurations or permissions issue.

Comment: I was able to replicate the same 405 error when I tried `queryAll` with a new REST API instance, created following the [MarkLogic's REST API instruction] (https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest/).

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you found your own answer, you can post and accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have just released version 3.3.1 of the Node client which fixes this bug.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please confirm the number of forests attached to your database? "queryAll" looks for forests before executing the query. This error looks more like an error while reading the forests than executing the query.

Comment: The database has three forests attached: my-db-dev-1, my-db-dev-2, my-db-dev-3.

Comment: Thank you.! Please file a github issue here - https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/issues . We might need few more details. Thanks.!

Comment: I've created [a github issue](https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/issues/837) as advised. Thanks!